# Store selected value from options in a PHP variable

Tags: php, jquery, html

I want to set selected value of a select input to a php variable. When I select a value from select box, then want to put that value in php variable and use echo select option value, but I can't get this value in select box inside php code. My Code is given below.

```
<body>
<select>
<?php
$test='<label id="output"></label>';
echo "<option>".$test."</option>";
?>
</select>

    <select id="sel">
        <option>--select--</option>
        <option>amr</option>
        <option>tomar</option>
    </select>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( "#sel" ).change(function() {
        var ww = $( "#sel" ).val();
        //alert(ww);
        $( "#output" ).text(ww);
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: You have to use ajax

Comment: PHP is run on the server, and html/javascript/jquery on the client. If a client changes the select value, you need to send a request to the server to let php use that value (with ajax).

It depends on what you want to do according with the select box. If you want to show certain text according to the selection, you don't need to use PHP. If you want to save the selected value in a database, you need PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use AJAX

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "some.php",
data: { ww: ww}
})
.done(function( msg ) {
alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
});
```

And in some.php using POST you can set `$ww = $_POST['ww'];`

Reference
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 1):

PHP is a server-side-language, so the php-code is executed before anything is showed on the screen.
That also means that when the page is loaded you can no longer interact with the php code.
For what it sounds like you're trying to do (a little hard to understand), it sounds like you need to use javascript to change the content on the page at runtime :)

Answer (score 0):

You're select box hasn't got an id of sel, which is what the JS is listening  for the change event on, I also can't see the div with the id output, which is where the results are going.`<select id="sel">` And `<div id="output"></div>`